# Find Chinese text in HTML using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-match

I'm attempting to get the text string from a string of HTML.
I would like to capture only the text between tags and skip over any empty tags.

My attempt is current attempt can be found here:
https://regex101.com/r/3Ujmw6/2

- I can't use \w since I need to capture Chinese characters
- I would like only text and not a lot of empty results

I have tried:

```
/>(\X+?)</g

//I will fail on nested tags, it capture the first nested tag
<p><strong>blablab</strong></p>
```

And this:

```
/>(\X*?)</g

//Finds me all the string, but also includes loads of empty strings
//for adjacent tags ><
```

Is there any way to exclude < from \X? Or is there a better way to write this so it returns only the text parts?

Comment: I'm fairly sure `\w` supports Chinese characters if you're using utf-8 ... I might be wrong though. Even so, you shouldn't really try to parse HTML with RegExp - it's the wrong tool for the job - use something like `DOMDocument()` instead.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work with  \w unless it's a limitation of the regexp site I'm using.
 
Thanks for the domcrawler suggestion, hadn't considered using it for crawling the text nodes. Pivoted to that solution.

Comment: May this function [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a regex like

```
>(\s*[^\s<][^<]*)
```

This simply matches all text between `>` and `<` that isn't all whitespace. See https://regex101.com/r/3Ujmw6/4.

Comment: Based on the comment by CD001 I went with the DomCrawler instead, yet your answer does do exactly what I asked for.